# Spatial Join - Grid Containing Points, Display Highest Value Only

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, spatial-join

Sorry if this has been answered--I couldn't find anything specific to my question, however.

- I have a polygon grid layer and a point layer which contains numerical values (1-4)
- I want to use a spatial join to colorize the grid based on the highest value point it contains.
- I'd like to do it in modelbuilder if possible, so I can easily incorporate it into my workflow.

For example:

[image]

Let's say the value 4 is colored red, 3 orange, 2 green, 1 blue.

In this example, the top left square would end up with a value of 4, the lower right square would end up with a value of 2, and the other squares would end up with values of 3.

Answer (score 3):

You should use spatial join geoprocessing tool and set the "Join Operation" to 
"JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE" :

> JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE —If multiple join features are found that have the
>   same spatial relationship with a single target feature, the attributes
>   from the multiple join features will be aggregated using a field map
>   merge rule.

Set the Merge Rule to Maximum for the value field from the point layer like the snapshot below:

[image]